# How can i get ActionBar items without dropdown and with icons?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i'm just thinking of designing my app a little bit more intuitive and came to this question. At this moment i have my actionBar with the logo of the app and the activity name on the left side and this three vertical dots (dropdown menu) on the other side.

I only got three items in the dropdown.

Can i have them with only icon in one row rather than in the dropdown menu?

Got my layout xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="jollocks.bierbrunnen.Bierbrunnen" >

<item 
android:id="@+id/hauptmenu" 
android:title="@string/hauptmenu"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:icon="@drawable/startseite">  
</item>

<item 
android:id="@+id/neustart"
android:title="@string/neustart"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:icon="@drawable/nochmal">
</item>
</menu>
```

Still the same.

Comment: [Yes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: Post your entire menu.xml @Jolle

Comment: Check my updated answer @Jolle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For learning different types of menu items you should refer 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

and

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

3 options available for displaying menus

1. always (Your requirement i.e it will display on `actionbar`)
2. ifRoom
3. never (Your current situation i.e display under dropdown)

---

For your updated question

Change
`android:showAsAction="always"`
to
`app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Thank you very much! :) this is great!